# Why the rationals do not form a countable intersection of open sets?

Tags: general-topology

Why is $\mathbb{Q}$ not a countable intersection of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$?

The hint shown in the book is to recall the Baire Category Theorem: A countable intersection of open dense sets in $\mathbb{R}$ is again dense.

Comment: Do you see why, if such an intersection existed, all of the sets being intersected must be dense?

Comment: Q is already dense, so what is the contradiction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $\mathbb{Q} = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n$ where $U_n$ are open. $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq U_n$ so $U_n$ are dense.

We have

$$\emptyset = (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}) \cap \mathbb{Q} = \left(\bigcap_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{R} \setminus \{q\}\right) \cap \left( \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n\right)$$

so $\emptyset$ is a countable intersection of dense open sets. This is a contradiction with your hint.